# 'Morning'-->countable or uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

1)There is written in the Macmillan dictionary that the word 'morning' can be **both: countable or uncountable**.

Could you give me an example sentence where 'morning' is uncountable?

2) Is 'morning' uncountable in the following sentence?

> He sat by the river **all morning**.

If not, could you explain why there is omitted "the" after "all"?*(not **'all the morning'** but **'all morning'**)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He sat by the river all morning.

In this sentence **morning** is uncountable because it refers to a particular period of time of a day.

But if you say

> He sits by the river every morning.

In this case morning is countable, because it refers to different mornings.

**The** is not used because **the** is used to specify or determine nouns but in this case morning is already determined by determiner **all**.